# Routed localization in identity pages in ASP.NET MVC Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am currently developing a web application in ASP.NET MVC Core where users should register. This is a localized web application that should be able to run for multiple languages. To be SEO friendly, I've chosen for routed localization, so my url's look like:
https://localhost:5001/en/Catalogue or https://localhost:5001/fr/catalogue.

To allow this, I added this piece of code in my ConfigureServices method in Startup.cs

```
services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");

        services.AddMvc()
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
            .AddViewLocalization()
            .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();
```

In my Configure method I added this:

```
IList<CultureInfo> supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
{
    new CultureInfo("en"),
    new CultureInfo("fr"),
};
var localizationOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions
{
    DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en"),
    SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
    SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
};
var requestProvider = new RouteDataRequestCultureProvider();
localizationOptions.RequestCultureProviders.Insert(0, requestProvider);

app.UseRouter(routes =>
{
    routes.MapMiddlewareRoute("{culture=en}/{*mvcRoute}", subApp =>
    {
        subApp.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions);

        subApp.UseMvc(mvcRoutes =>
        {
            mvcRoutes.MapRoute(
                name: "areaRoute",
                template: "{culture=en}/{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            mvcRoutes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{culture=en}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    });
});
```

This works like a charm. I can translate my MVC pages in any flavour I want. My problem is with the identiy pages. I added those pages as scaffolded items. Their URL's are pointing to https://localhost:5001/Identity/Account/Register. Trying to access them with https://localhost:44339/en/Identity/Account/Register does not work. How can I implement routed localization with identity pages?

Comment: This may be a stupid question but can't you use attribute routing to manually set some of those problem page routes? https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/

Comment: Hi Iskander, i can do that for my views - which i did as you can see from the code I attached to the original question - but i can't do that for the identity razor pages. I anyway don't like the fact that Microsoft is using Razor pages for those identity scaffolded items.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[AddAreaFolderRouteModelConvention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.applicationmodels.pageconventioncollection.addareapageroutemodelconvention?view=aspnetcore-2.2) will do the magic:

```
services.AddMvc()
    .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
    {
        options.Conventions.AddAreaFolderRouteModelConvention("Identity", "/Account/", model =>
         {
             model.Selectors.ForEach(x =>
             {
                 if (x.AttributeRouteModel.Template.StartsWith("Identity"))
                 {
                     x.AttributeRouteModel = new AttributeRouteModel()
                     {
                         Order = -1,
                         Template = AttributeRouteModel.CombineTemplates(("{culture=en-US}"),
                             x.AttributeRouteModel.Template)
                     };
                 }
             });


         });
    });
```

MSDN page says:

> pageName String The page name e.g. /Users/List
>
> The page name is the path of the file without extension, relative to
>   the pages root directory for the specified area. e.g. the page name
>   for the file Areas/Identity/Pages/Manage/Accounts.cshtml, is
>   /Manage/Accounts.

So all pages are actually inside "/Account/", here are some generated links:

```
/en-us/identity/account/login
/en-us/identity/account/manage/index
/en-us/identity/account/manage/orders
```

if you don't like "/identity/" inside path, you can do this:

```
AttributeRouteModel.CombineTemplates(("{culture=en-US}"), 
  x.AttributeRouteModel.Template.Substring("Identity/".Length)) //<==Substring
```

Then all links will be:

```
/en-us/account/login
/en-us/account/manage/index
/en-us/account/manage/orders
```

[image]