# MapAreaControllerRoute for Identity area in .NET Core 6 does not work

Tags: asp.net-core, routes, asp.net-identity, .net-6.0, area

This customization takes no effect:

```
app.MapAreaControllerRoute(
     name: "Identity",
     areaName: "Identity",
     pattern: "Identity/xx/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

`MapAreaControllerRoute` has been added right before the default `MapControllerRoute` in `Program.cs` main function

PS: in `Identity` area there is no controller so you can't add an area attribute there

Comment: To use the `MapAreaControllerRoute` method, in the Area controller, we need to add the `Area` attribute. `PS: in Identity area there is no controller so you can't add an area attribute there`, If there isn't a controller in the Area, why do you use the `MapAreaControllerRoute` method? If you just want to display the view page, why not directly using Razor page? More detail information about Areas, see [Areas in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Comment: the thing is that i have to modify route in area Razor page  , i need it for localization: need to make this work https://localhost:7044/en/Identity/Account/Login

Comment: For the Asp.net Core Identity page, since they are razor pages, to configure localization route for them, you need to use the `AddAreaFolderRouteModelConvention` method, refer to this thread: [Routed localization in identity pages in ASP.NET MVC Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54261042/routed-localization-in-identity-pages-in-asp-net-mvc-core).

Comment: thank you very much @ZhiLv , it worked , only one thing:  when [Authorize] attribute is specified on regular Action/Contoller this rule is not applied , do you know how to resolve that case?

Comment: What do you mean about the `this rule is not applied`? In our previous discussion, we will use the `AddAreaFolderRouteModelConvention` method to add configure the localization route for the Asp.net core Identity Scaffold Razor pages, instead of applying to the MVC controller. So, I'm not very clear about your new question, since it is a new question, I suggest you can create a new thread, and explain more detail about your new question, then all community members will see it and help you solve it.

Comment: Hi @Armen Khachatryan, for the original question, I converted the solution into an answer, hopefully it can help others who meet the same question in the feature. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To configure localization route for the Asp.net core Identity Scaffold Razor pages, we can use the `AddAreaFolderRouteModelConvention` method to add Convention, like this:

```
services.AddMvc()
    .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
    {
        options.Conventions.AddAreaFolderRouteModelConvention("Identity", "/Account/", model =>
         {
             model.Selectors.ForEach(x =>
             {
                 if (x.AttributeRouteModel.Template.StartsWith("Identity"))
                 {
                     x.AttributeRouteModel = new AttributeRouteModel()
                     {
                         Order = -1,
                         Template = AttributeRouteModel.CombineTemplates(("{culture=en-US}"),
                             x.AttributeRouteModel.Template)
                     };
                 }
             }); 
         });
    });
```

Refer to this thread: [Routed localization in identity pages in ASP.NET MVC Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54261042/routed-localization-in-identity-pages-in-asp-net-mvc-core).