URL culture transform not working in Identity pages integrated with Asp.Net Core 6 MVC project
I'm working on an Asp.Net Core 6 MVC project that integrated Identity for user management.
I added the language localization for English and Japanese and it works as by cookie culture transformation.
I want to enable the URL culture transform, so added the culture to url mapper as following.
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{culture}/{controller=First}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

But it's only for the MVC structured pages, not for Razor pages in the Identity.
It maps the culture (en or ja) to Razor pages, but it shows a http 404 error.
And when I changed some code to enable the url culture in razor pages, the url relocation didn't work from MVC views to Identity razor pages and vice versa.
I'm looking for the solution to satisfy the following requirements.

URL Culture transformation
Cookie Culture transformation
Smooth relocation between MVC views and Identity Razor pages.

I'm waiting for your advice to solve this problem.
Thank you.
I added the culture part to the MapControllerRoute in my program.cs file.
But it didn't work for Identity razor pages like Login, Register etc.

Regarding MVC views and Identity Razor pages, you can use the AddAreaPageRouteModelConvention method to create and add an IPageRouteModelConvention to add a routing model convention for all pages in the specified area and folder. For details, you can refer to this link :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54261042/routed-localization-in-identity-pages-in-asp-net-mvc-core

Thank you for your advice.
I'll try it in my project.
